# how can i set a fixed background and scroll in css?

Tags: html, css

how can i set a fixed background and scroll in css??? and also ive been trying to set a background to cover all dimensions by i always end up with a blurry background :(

im relatively new at this so please dont judge me, this is my css:
    body 
    #bg 
    {
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0px; 
    top: 0px; 
    z-index: 0;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    }

```
.stretch
{
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-attachment:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

This oe is fixed, set body to 100% to make full screen: http://jsfiddle.net/X8Z2v/4/

This one is scrolling by: http://jsfiddle.net/X8Z2v/5/

```
 html, body {
        height:3000px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
    }
    .stretch {
        position: absolute;
        left:0;
        right:0;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        background-image: url(http://www.placehold.it/2000x1000);
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center;
        background-attachment: scroll;
    }
```

HTML

```
<div class="stretch"></div>
```

Comment: i want to be able to scroll and have the background not move at all, just the elements, all my elements position are set to absolute, and do you know how i can set the background like in the example you have without losing caption???

Comment: Do you want a background for the body on your page? That'll be this: http://jsfiddle.net/X8Z2v/6/

Comment: whups. Gave the background image to `<html>` as well.... http://jsfiddle.net/X8Z2v/7/